# change unfocused text field icon Color through app themeData

Tags: flutter

i want to change the unfocused Text field icon color.

through primary color i can change the focused icon color like the 2nd text field, i want to change the first one (the not clicked one).

i want to change it in the whole app, so i am using [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) in my main MaterialApp

ex: i want the unfocused text field icon color be purple and the focused one be red.

[image]

UPDATE: 08/JUN/19
i made an issue for flutter team as i thought this needs to be in flutter framework itself not a workaround it with foucs node
[Issue Link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33183)
and looks like there is an PR for it [PR Link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/33333)

Answer (score 3):

By using a `FocusNode` to determine when the `TextField` is unfocused, and then assign the color you desire to `Icon()` of `prefixicon`, and when focused show the default theme color :

```
FocusNode fieldNode = FocusNode();
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
  child: TextField(
    focusNode: fieldNode,
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'account',
        labelText: 'Label',
        hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle,
            color: fieldNode.hasFocus
                ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                : Colors.purple)),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
    controller: firstNameController,
  ),
),
```

Comment: that's great workaround, but i wonder why i can't override it through themeData instead of that grey

Comment: I didn't try that, but I guess it is possible.

Comment: i will try it once i reach home and get back to you ^_^